# 7zip / Powershell copying changed items with parent directory

Tags: powershell, compression, backup, 7zip

I have the following script block built into my script:

```
$changedItems = (Get-ChildItem $srcdirectory -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-24)} | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }).FullName

    foreach ($changedItem in $changeditems){ 
        $archivePath = Join-Path -Path $dstDirectory -ChildPath ($archiveName + "_" + $fileDate + ".zip")
        $7zipArgs = @(
        "a";        
        "-mx=9";    
        "-tzip";    
        $archivePath;
        $changedItem;
    )
    7zip @7zipArgs
    }
```

It is simply supposed to identify items, that have changed in the last 24 hours, and archive them into a zip directory.

The source directory, that I am querying, has a lot of data in it, so the following part of the block allows, so that only changed *files* are copied:

```
| where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
```

This eliminates the following problem that happens with the *-Recurse* part of *Get-Childitem*:

If there was a folder, which had been changed recently, but no files inside of the folder were changed, the whole folder and it's complete content would be archived.

HOWEVER:

Now I only have the changed files that I want, but I don't have any hierarchy in my new zip file. All of the files are just directly in the zip file, with no parent directory whatsoever.

Example:

Changed files from source directory:

```
SourceDirectory\A\B\file1
SourceDirectory\1\file2
SourceDirectory\x\y\z\file3
```

Come into the new zipped ***archive.zip*** like this:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

But I want to keep the parent directories in the **archive.zip** like this:

```
A\B\file1
1\file2
x\y\z\file3
```

Is there any way to do this?

I hope the explanation is not too complex, please feel free to ask for more information if it is not clear. I needed to add that much context because it is a very specific problem.

Thanks for all help and tips.

Comment: Your variables `$dstDirectory`, `$archiveName` and `$filedate` seem to come from nowhere.. You should take them from the properties of the [FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) object `$changedItem`

Comment: Hi @Theo, Thanks for your comment! This is only part of the script, the variables you are mentioning are defined earlier on in the script. Could you please elaborate why it would help if I defined them from the properties of $changedItem? Thanks!